# voltage regulator vs dc dc converter

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc-dc-converter

I'm abit confused with the different products, DC-DC converter and Voltage regulators. Can this [voltage regulator](https://no.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Analog-Devices-Linear-Technology/LT1339CNPBF?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtitjHzVIkrqV3wN4vO7OWzflRqK34nmWnr9MNLNEwasQ%3D%3D) be used in the same way as this [DC-DC converter](https://no.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Murata-Power-Solutions/UWE-12-10-Q48PB-C?qs=02kMkzikyGLQSNZCy6RAhQ%3D%3D)?

Thank you.
Steffen

Comment: The voltage regulator, when looking at the datasheet, looks alot more complicated than a converter, does it need all the extra components?

Comment: The first part is a controller, you need a lot of external components. The second part is a complete module.

Comment: that makes sense. The controller is one of the main components of a DCDC converter?

Comment: Steffen, when learning a new topic, the first thing to conquer is the vocabulary. Voltages are not stated in "amounts". Use the word "level" when referring to voltages of different magnitudes. Using the correct words, terms and phrases will allow your questions to be more appropriately and accurately answered by those who can help you.

Comment: The former may well be part of the latter. The mentioned DC-DC converter is a module containing a switching controller, like the LT1339 plus all the other components.

Comment: Small amounts means you need a number of different outputs from a single input of 48V?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One major difference is that the Murata module has a transformer which allows them to provide galvanic isolation between input and output. This would allow, for example, you to have a -48V telecom type input and output a 5V rail with 0V grounded.

The LT1339 "High Power Synchronous DC/DC Controller" **can** be applied like that, however the circuit is even more complex than the minimal circuit shown at the front of the datasheet, and requires a custom wound transformer. All that stuff is built into the module, including the parts that are sensitive to layout.

[image]

The Murata module also operates at a somewhat higher frequency than the maximum for the LT chip, so you can expect the magnetics to be more compact and lighter.

Answer (score 9):

There is a great video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=giGRrODKJSE). In short, if you have a high current output you should take buck converter, for lower current a voltage regulator is the better choice. Why? A buck converter has a greater efficiency when the current is "high" but it's lower then the voltage regulater efficiency when the current is low.

> The linear regulator has a much cleaner output voltage than a buck converter in most cases. So if your circuit is sensitive to changes in the input voltage a linear regulator may be better.

comment from youtube.

Answer (score 4):

The voltage regulator (as you call it) is an LT1339 synchronous buck controller and requires a bunch of components around it to give it functionality: -

[image]

The DC-DC convertor is a Murata isolating flyback module: -

[image]

So really you are comparing apples with pears. However, there are overlaps in usage.